# how do i sort datagridview by cell color?

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors, cell, background-color

i want to sort my datagridview by cell background color .
for example :
which rows that cell[1] is red , priority in first .
and which rows that cell is white , priority in second.

in bellow code , i change background color of cell.

```
DataGridViewCellStyle FormTypeCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        FormTypeCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["FormID"].Value.ToString() != Convert.ToString(SettingVariables.FormID_NormReqFromBb))
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["PersianName"].Style = FormTypeCellStyle;
            } 
        }
```

now i want sort my datagridview by cell color .please help me , how do i can this ?

Comment: Sorting DataGridView is a kind of headache if you do not use DataTable as a binding source. I recommend you use DataTable as a binding source and add some additional columns for sorting. You can hide the additional columns and once you click 'sort' button, create a DataView from the DataTable and use it for the binding source.

Comment: you may try in this link https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T256782/sorting-by-cell-color

Answer (score 1):

You can order the datasource by the same condition, you set the color

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = data.OrderBy(x => x.FormID != Convert.ToString(SettingVariables.FormID_NormReqFromBb));
```